# Multiple filters on a data-set

Tags: filter

I have a list of things and I want to filter them based on a text input AND categories implemented using vertical tabs.

Currently the categories tabs have precedence over the text input, as in: the text input filters out the results under the current category only.

Is that something users can find non-intuitive and wonder why they're not finding something?
What would be the easiest solution to rectify this issue?

Comment: is there any chance you can add a screenshot? Your description is difficult to visualise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be confusing. If the user is not allowed to use text search alone, it can be solved by a simple notification:

**You are now searching for "BMW" under "Automotives" category**

Or, if the user is allowed to use each filter independently as well, you can simply ask him, look at the Reddit approach:

[image]

The user would know if he unchecks that option, the search would become global, otherwise it will be a sub-search for a subreddit, or in your case a category.